# How to import all under a function

Tags: python, sql, function, tkinter, import

I have a login screen that once logged in will take me to a page that has two buttons. Canteen page button, and admin page button.

my first problem is that once I open my canteen page by pressing the button everything that's inside this page doesn't seem to be working. I assume I have to 'import * from Canteen' although I cant import all under a module.
my second problem is the same as the first just with my Admin screen.

```
def adminpage():
    import Admin

def canteenpage():
    import Canteen

find_user = ('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? and password = ?')
        c.execute(find_user,[(self.username.get()),(self.password.get())])
        result = c.fetchall()
        if result:
            root=Tk()
            root.geometry("400x400")
            root.title("Select Page")
            Label(text = "welcome to the dashboard").pack()
            Button(root, text = "Canteen Page",command=canteenpage).pack()
            Button(root, text = "Admin Page",command=adminpage).pack()
```

Comment: did you try `from Canteen import *` ?

Comment: yes i did, but i cant import all under a function

Answer (score 0):

You should put all the code in the other module(In your case "Admin" and "Canteen") in a class. That would work for you.

Like I have done in this example:

Module_1:

```
import tkinter as tk


def test_func():
    from Module_2 import TestClass


root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: test_func())
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Module_2:

```
class TestClass:
    import tkinter as tk
    root = tk.Toplevel()
    lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Test Label")
    lbl.pack()
```

This will work for you

Comment: I want to call my Canteen and Admin Page when I click a button. Although I cant       ' import * ' under a function as it won't work. If I import it at the top then the screen will open without me pressing a button.

Comment: @SakariyeAhmed I have edited the answer now. Please make sure to accept the answer if it works for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

As my comment stated if you would like to import the contents of a module you do `from Canteen import *`

However I don't think importing a module would encapsulate the behaviour you would like to achieve. Your code seems to suggest that you would like to serve the result of a database query in a new window.

For that kind of behaviour I suggest checking out either [message widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/message.htm) or [messagebox widget](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-standard-dialogs.htm) of `tkinter` and adapt your code to use either one of them.