# My page variables won't work when I'm linking pages together

Tags: python, tkinter, import, linker

I've got 3 pages. a Login screen, a Canteen page, and an Admin Page. When I log in I have two options: either click a button to take me to the Canteen Page or click a button to take me to the Admin page. Opening these pages with the buttons work, however, the variables in those screens won't work.

The function All is everything selected in my canteen and admin pages. I have no idea why the variables won't work when I call them like this, but the pages on its own do work.

```
def CallCanteen():
    from practice import All
def CallAdmin():
    from Admin import All

 if result:
            self.master.destroy()
            root=Tk()
            root.geometry("400x400")
            root.title("Canteen System")
            Label(text = "welcome to the dashboard").pack()
            Button(root, text = "Canteen Page", command=CallCanteen).pack()
            Button(root, text = "Admin Page",command=CallAdmin).pack()
```

Yes I have tried:

```
def CallCanteen():
    from practice import *
def CallAdmin():
    from Admin import *
```

but that makes a syntax error.

Comment: What does "variables won't work" mean? Also, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: In my Canteen page, i have a check button, so when clicked it can open a textbox where i can insert a number. If the check button is not clicked the state is disabled so the textbox won't open. the page works perfectly. when I try to import this page, the page opens up however my check buttons won't allow me to open the textbox.

Comment: Does this your Question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59605298/how-to-import-all-under-a-function/59610058#59610058

Answer (score 0):

You should put all the code in the other modules(In your case "Admin" and "practice") inside a class. That would work for you.

Like I have done in this example:

Module_1:

```
import tkinter as tk


def test_func():
    from Module_2 import TestClass


root = tk.Tk()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Click", command=lambda: test_func())
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Module_2:

```
class TestClass:
    import tkinter as tk
    examle_variable = 0
    root = tk.Tk()
    lbl = tk.Label(root, text="Test Label")
    lbl.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

To access any variable use the `class` name before its name.
In this example: `TestClass.example_variable`

This will work for you